# Superfluous conditions for showing closedness of support of a coherent sheaf on a noetherian scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was proving the following statement

> Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme, and $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent sheaf on $X$. Then, the support of $\mathcal{F}$ is closed.

Here is my proof:

> Cover $X$ by affine open $U_i = \text{Spec}{A_i}$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent, $\mathcal{F}|_{U_i} \simeq \widetilde{M_i}$ where $M_i$ is a finitely generated $A_i$-module. By the fact that if $M$ is finitely generated we have $\text{supp}(\widetilde{M}) = V(\text{Ann}(M))$, we have $\text{supp}(\mathcal{F}|_{U_i}) = V(\text{Ann}(M_i))$ for each $i$. Thus, $\text{supp}(\mathcal{F}|_{U_i}) = \text{supp}(\mathcal{F})\cap U_i$ is closed in each $U_i$, so $\text{supp}(\mathcal{F})$ is closed in $X$.

I have nowhere used the fact that $X$ can be covered by finitely many affine opens, since the last statement holds for any open cover, not just finite. (This can be easily proved) Is the noetherian condition superfluous, or is there an error in my proof? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is indeed superfluous. See Cor. 7.31, p. 192 in Liu's book.

Comment: In fact, the full strength of coherence is also unnecessary: all that is required is a quasi-coherent sheaf of finite type, and then your proof suffices. (In general, coherent = finite type plus the condition that any kernel of any morphism over any open set is also of finite type.)